# logback: sign log file before rolling

Tags: java, logback, gnupg

We have a requirement to sign log files. We would like to sign the log file when it is rolled. `GPG` can be used to`clearsign` the file.

**Question**: we need to sign and save the log file when it is rolled. Is there a way this can be done with logback?

Answer (score 1):

I think your only option to do this in Logback is to extend (subclass) logic of [RollingFileAppender](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) with your logic (gpg signing, for example using library [bouncy-gpg](https://github.com/neuhalje/bouncy-gpg)) and then use your own appender in logger configuration.